# why did elasticsearch designed "store" field?

Tags: elasticsearch

By default, field values are indexed to make them searchable, but they are not stored. This means that the field can be queried, but the original field value cannot be retrieved.

I am curious how does the implementation work on Elasticsearch backend works. How can they make a value not retrievable but searchable? (I would imagine it would need to be stored somewhere in order for you to search it right?) Why is Elasticsearch designed this way? what efficiency did it achieve for designing it this way?

Answer (score 1):

The source document is actually ["stored" in the `_source` field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html) (but it is not indexed) and all fields of the source documents are indexed (but not stored). All field values can usually be retrieved from the `_source` field using [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-source-filtering). This is how ES is configured by default, but you're free to change that.

You can, for instance, decide to not store the `_source` document at all and store only certain fields of your document. This might be a good idea if for instance your document has a field which contains a huge blob of text. It might not be wise to store the `_source` because that would take a lot of space for nothing. That huge blob of text might only be useful for full-text search and so would only need to be indexed, while all other fields might need to be indexed and stored as well because they need to be retrieved in order to be displayed.

So the bottom line is:

- if a field can be searched, it doesn't need to be stored, it only needs to be indexed
- if a field can be retrieved, it can either be configured to be stored or retrieved/filtered from the `_source` field (which is stored by default)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I think you might have some conflict points that I mentioned that I do not understand. I figured it has to be "stored" in elastic in order for us to search it. Since it is stored, why is it being designed as I cannot retrieve it. Assuming I am not looking for full-text search on this field, I can't seem to understand why when I cannot fetch the record with this field included. I feel like elastic is not losing any efficiency for showing a field that is not indexed, and I want to know why it is being designed this way.

Comment: ["store"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-store.html) and ["indexed"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html) are two different things. The former means that the field itself is stored in addition to being stored in the `_source` document as well while the latter simply means that the field is queryable. The way it is designed provides you with maximum flexibility because you are free to decide to change the defaults and store whatever you want (or not) and make whatever you want queryable (or not)

Comment: My question is why would a field be queryable but not retrievable? what efficiency is it achieving?

Comment: For flexibility purposes, sometimes you just need to query some field without having to retrieve that field, but another set of fields from the matching document. The most optimal settings is to 1) not store the `_source` document 2) index only fields that you want to query/aggregate/sort on and 3) store only fields that you want to display. the fields in 2 and 3 are not necessarily the same depending on the use case.

Comment: I do not think my question is answered: what efficiency is elastic achieving for allow me to query but not store it?  My question is why isn't elastic store it since it has to "store" it in order for me to query it anyways. What efficiency is elastic achieving for choose not to allow me to pull up that data?

Comment: You have the choice to index and/or store anything you want. Elastic doesn't forces you to choose or the other. When Lucene processes data, it stores the same information (in a different way or format) in [several different files](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_4_1/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene84/package-summary.html#package.description) in order to facilitate future work with that data (queries, aggregations, scoring, sorting, etc). From the previous link, check `Index Structure Overview` and you'll see that the same data eventually ends up in different files with different purposes.

Comment: Of special interest to you should be this `Fields may be stored, in which case their text is stored in the index literally, in a non-inverted manner. Fields that are inverted are called indexed. A field may be both stored and indexed.` The former end up in the `Stored Field values` file while the latter end up in the `Term dictionary`. Both of those files achieve a different purpose in Lucene.